# How to call AngularJs function inside laravel input field

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I have an HTML form. And I can use successfully angular js in that form.
But when I convert that form field using laravel form builder I got an error.

This is my simple HTML and AngularJs and it's work fine

```js
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);
app.controller('availableDay', function($scope) {
  $scope.dayfrom = "";
  $scope.dayto = "";
  $scope.dayfull = function() {
    return $scope.dayfrom + "-" + $scope.dayto;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row" ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller = "availableDay">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h4 class="page-header">Available in a week</h4>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Day From</label>
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model = "dayfrom">
                        <option>Monday</option>
                        <option>Tuesday</option>
                        <option>Wednesday</option>
                        <option>Thursday</option>
                        <option>Friday</option>
                        <option>Saturday</option>
                        <option>Sunday</option>
                    </select>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Day To</label>
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="dayto">
                        <option>Monday</option>
                        <option>Tuesday</option>
                        <option>Wednesday</option>
                        <option>Thursday</option>
                        <option>Friday</option>
                        <option>Saturday</option>
                        <option>Sunday</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Available Day</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{dayfull()}}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div> 
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

But when I am going to convert it using laravel form builder an error occurred

> syntax error, unexpected '}'

```js
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);
        app.controller('availableDay', function($scope) {
            $scope.dayfrom = "";
            $scope.dayto = "";
            $scope.dayfull = function() {
                return $scope.dayfrom + "-" + $scope.dayto;
            }
        });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row" ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller = "availableDay">

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h4 class="page-header">Available in a week</h4>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">

                    {{ Form::label("day from","Day From ") }}
    
                    {{ Form::select('day_from', [
                       'Monday' => 'Monday',
                       'Tuesday' => 'Tuesday',
                       'Wednesday' => 'Wednesday',
                       'Thursday' => 'Thursday',
                       'Friday' => 'Friday',
                       'Saturday' => 'Saturday',
                       'Sunday' => 'Sunday'], null, ['class' => 'form-control',
                       'ng-model' => 'dayfrom']
                    ) }}
                    
                </div>
            </div>    

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label("day to","Day To ") }}
    
                    {{ Form::select('day_to', [
                       'Monday' => 'Monday',
                       'Tuesday' => 'Tuesday',
                       'Wednesday' => 'Wednesday',
                       'Thursday' => 'Thursday',
                       'Friday' => 'Friday',
                       'Saturday' => 'Saturday',
                       'Sunday' => 'Sunday'], null, ['class' => 'form-control',
                       'ng-model' => 'dayto']
                    ) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label("available day","Available Day ") }}

                    {{ Form::text("available_day", {{dayfull()}}, ["class" => "form-control"]) }}
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How can I use that AngularJs function {{dayfull()}} inside Laravel form builder?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem here is that you can't use it in this format. The blade and angularjs markups conflict, as shown [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs). One way you could get around it is to concatenate the markup, so when it echoes, angularjs SHOULD process it:

```
{{ Form::text("available_day", '{{'.'dayfull()'.'}}', ["class" => "form-control"]) }}
```